# Unable to programmatically reset UINavigationController.presentedViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I wrote this Xcode playground example to demonstrate a problem I'm having:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let rootViewController = UIViewController()
rootViewController.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 640.0, height: 640.0))
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController

var alertController: UIAlertController! = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "This is a test", preferredStyle: .alert)
rootViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

alertController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
rootViewController.presentedViewController

alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Another Test", message: "This is another test", preferredStyle: .alert)
rootViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

rootViewController.presentedViewController!.title
```

My expectation would be that the title for the presentedViewController would be **"Another Test"**. The title actually is **"Test"**, indicating that the navigation controller  still seems to maintain the original presented view controller, even though it was dismissed.

What would be the proper way to programmatically reset the presentedViewController for a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that the animations take time and you're calling the second present before the first completes its presentation and dismissal. Even with animate false, these calls take some time. If you use the completion closures and chain these together, the second alert appears with the correct title:

```
let rootViewController = UIViewController()
rootViewController.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 640.0, height: 640.0))
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController

var alertController: UIAlertController! = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "This is a test", preferredStyle: .alert)

rootViewController.present(alertController, animated: true) {
    alertController.dismiss(animated: false) {
        alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Another Test", message: "This is another test", preferredStyle: .alert)
        rootViewController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

If you run your original code from Xcode, you'll see the following message in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fab67825200> on <TestProject.ViewController: 0x7fab66d0e090> while a presentation is in progress!
```

This is telling you that the first alert controller is still being presented when the call to present the second is made.